# Estimation for a polynomial of degree less than $k$.

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we have a polynomial in $\lvert t\rvert$ of degree less than $k$ for some $k>0$, say $Q(\lvert t\rvert)$.

Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary small.

> > The claim is that there exists some $C(\varepsilon)$ such that
> >     $$
> > Q(\lvert t\rvert)\le C e^{\varepsilon\lvert t\rvert}.
> > $$

How can I prove that?

I think this has something to do with the fact that exponential grwoth is faster than polynomial one.

Comment: If you use the series definition of e you can write it as an infinitely long polynomial...try going from there

Comment: Let $Q(\lvert t\rvert)=a_{k-1}\lvert t\rvert^{k-1}+\cdots +a_0$, then choosing $C\ge\max_{0\le j\le k-1}\frac{j! a_j}{\varepsilon^j}$ should make it.

Comment: Yeah that looks correct to me :)